# Recursive combinatorial solution for number of sequences of {0,1,2}

Tags: combinatorics

How do we approach a recursive solution to this combinatorial question?

> In how many sequences of length $n$ that are made of the numbers ${0,1,2}$ that the sum of two consecutive digits is either 1, 2, or 3?

I have reached the fact that this question is equal to the question:

> In how many sequences of length $n$ that are made of numbers ${0,1,2}$, where there are never two zero's next to each other or two 2's next to each other?

How does one solve this?

Comment: For reference, here is the [closed form answer](http://math.fau.edu/cgtc/cgtc41/Abstracts/RGrimaldi.pdf), and here is the beginning of the [sequence in Sloane's encyclopedia](http://oeis.org/A001333).  In the Sloane reference, it's interesting to see the other quantities these numbers are counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 3 separate recursive sequences $n_{i,0}, n_{i,1}$ and $n_{i,2}$ that each count the number of sequences in $\{0,1,2 \}$ of length $i$ that end in 0, 1 or 2 respectively with no double 2s or double 0s. Clearly the total number of sequences of length $i$ satisfying your requirements is $n_{i} = n_{i,0}+n_{i,1}+n_{i,2}$. Now we have relations

$n_{i+1, 0} = n_{i,1} + n_{i,2}$

$n_{i+1,1} = n_{i,0} + n_{i,1} + n_{i,2}$

$n_{i+1,2} = n_{i,0} + n_{i,1}$,

with initial data $n_{1,0} = n_{1,1} = _{1,2} = 1$.

Solve these recursively to get your general solution $n_{i}$.

Comment: Symmetry gives $n_{i,0}=n_{i,2}$, which eases the solution.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get the 3 equations again?

Comment: @TheNotMe To get a string of length $i+1$ ending in a 0 we can add a 0 to the end of a string of length $i$ ending in a 1 or a 2, but not one ending in a $0$ as then we would have a double 0. Thus the number of strings of length $i+1$ ending in a zero is the numbersof strings of length $i$ ending in a 1 or a 2. $n_{i+1,0} = n_{i, 1} + n_{i,2}$. The other equations are obtained in the same way, adding a 1 or a 2 at the end of other strings.

Comment: And as Ross says, $n_{i,0}=n_{i,2}$ so that should help find the solution.